# Please name some tutorial for MVC3 , which shows data transferring from Controller to View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, model, controller

Iam just a beginner in MVC , and i have doubts like , how to pass data from two ActionResults to the same view...
and then at view how to get these two values returned from the controller...

So far, iam able to list , edit and create the table rows from a database. My next step is to show a list as well as a label , both filled dynamically from the model object which i receive in view...

But iam not sure how i can get two different values from one model object i recieve at  view..
or may be i am wrong in passing the list and a value , from the controller actions...

So, Please give some idea, or some good video or other tutorials , which can help me in this step..

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to open the sample project that comes with MVC.  It used to be called Nerd Dinner but the new one is a movie database found [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3)

One thing you are going to want to research is Form View Models.  Essentially you pass a class back to the view from your action result and read that in your view.

Something like this;

```
MyModel myFVM = new MyModel
myFVM.SomeData = "Some data"
Return View(myFVM)
```

Then your view needs to inherit from the class;

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyModel>
```

Then to get values

```
<%= Model.SomeData %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will check that.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you want to display some thing in view. you can go for the following options ]

1. ViewData : ViewData is a dictionary of objects that is derived from ViewDataDictionary class and accessible using strings as keys.
2. ViewBag : Dynamic wrapper to store the values.
3. Staticaly Typed ViewModel class. create a class and add properties and method which is needed to that particularview. I prefere viewModel

model class

```
 public class SomePageViewModel
    {
      public string EmployeeName{get;set;}
      public string EmployeeCode{get;set;}
    }
```

controller

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
  var somedata=GetSomeDataFor(SomePageviewModel obj);// change your logic here
   return view(somedata);
}
```

in the view use the model

```
@model yourNamespace.SomePageViewModel
```

for the tutorials i think this list would be helpful for you

1. [Asp.net MVC tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials)
2. [Pluralsight-asp.net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/pluralsight-building-applications-with-aspnet-mvc-4)